# Why my django registration form does not pass is_valid()

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and was following a tutorial on how to build a register view. I did exactly the same but my form does not pass form.is_valid().

Here is what I did:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

views.py

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    form = MyRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})

def register_success(request):
    return render(request, 'register_success.html')
```

register.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Register</h2>
<form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}

<input type="submit" value="Register" />

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

When I tried to register new users on the webpage, none of them passed. Even when I used username: testuser email: testuser@example.com password:testuser123, it failed. So what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try in views method `print form.errors` and see what that says.

Comment: @ShangWang Oh, thank you. It works. Seems like the problem is the password is too similar to the username.

Comment: Glad that you found out the answer. However your project is not complete without showing the actual validation error back to the template. Checkout the answers from others below to write a complete view.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the correct view pattern. Put the line `form = MyRegistrationForm()` inside an else block, then the page itself will tell you why the form is not valid.